# Is that possible to push message to all the devices registered with a Application ID?

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to push my message to GCM server with PHP code, which runs and triggered on server.

The Code available is only to push to specific registration IDs in form of array. I am trying to avoid storing the registration IDs of the devices and pushing to all the Registered device under the application ID/Sender ID.

Is that possible to broad cast too all the devices.

The PHP code i use is,

```
<?php

$regID=$_GET['regID'];
$registatoin_ids=array($regID);
$msg=array("message"=>'HI Testing');
$url='https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields=array(
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => $msg
);
$headers=array(
    'Authorization: key=AIzaSyDioLlUNZYx0qxXzB92x8kJHcKvz4PGArM',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fields));
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Follow this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: How can a server know which device you are targeting without the id? There is a kind of multicast broadcast in that you can send to 1000 devices at the same time but you still need to provide the ids of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to broadcast a GCM message to all registered devices without speifying the registration IDs of those devices. You can't avoid sending the registration IDs to your server and storing them there.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#target)

It is possible to send push messages up to **1000** devices in one HTTP Request.

Comment: is that sending upto 1000 devices without device registration id?

Comment: no you need to add that to `registration_ids` array and send. Refer http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe devices to GCM topics with the new GCM PubSub feature:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

> GCM topic messaging allows your app server to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. Based on the publish/subscribe model, topic messaging supports up to one million subscriptions per app. The app server sends messages with payloads up to 2KB to the topic, and GCM handles the message routing and delivers the message reliably to the right devices. For example, users of a weather forecasting app could opt in to a "severe weather alerts" topic and receive notifications of storms threatening specified areas.

Then, you'll be able to send a tiny HTTP request to GCM, specifying only the topic name.

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
   }
}
```